# Como instalar xampp en MacOS?

Tags: xampp, macos

descargue el wamp desde la pagina [apachefriends.com](https://www.apachefriends.org) pero me descarga un archivo .bz2 no dmg y cuando lo descomprimo me sale un archivo .cpgz pero en el tutorial de la pagina dice que debe ser un .dmg

El archivo .cpgz me genera un nuevo archivo .bz2 y luego nuevamente este un .cpgz asi en un ciclo infinito, por favor si alguien sabe como instalar XAMPP le agradeceria su ayuda, muchas gracias.

Adjunto imagenes donde se puede observar las extensiones y varios intentos de descomprimir que hice.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta otra imagen muestra la extension que descarga

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Amigo, en esa página descargas XAMPP, no es WAMP (sirve pa lo mismo pero vale la pena aclarar, que por ahí sigues un tutorial y fijo no encuentras las opciones en el mismo lugar). Y acabo de probar en esa página, el enlace de xampp for macos y me ofrece descarga de `xampp-osx-8.0.3-vm.dmg`. De qué parte de la página descargaste el instalador?

Comment: eso es lo que ofrece, pero descarga otra extension .bz2 intenta descargarlo a ver.

Comment: @Alfabravo ademas wamp es solo para windows y yo necesito para mac o donde hay un instalador de wamp para macOS?

Answer (score 2):

Cambié la extensión de .bz2 a .dmg y ya instaló.

Comment: Jajaja, quién sabe qué cosa en el navegador, el OS o en medio, te está cambiando las cosas. Descargué varias versiones y todas bajan como dmg, las abrí con 7zip y veo los archivos ahí dentro. Rarísimo!

Comment: Jajajaja, estabas usando chrome? Parece que es [culpa del navegador](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?t=80325) y con Safari eso no pasa...

Comment: Si, uso chrome, safari no es de mis afectos... de hecho soy nuevo en este mundo de mac... lo estoy usando para poder criticarlo con bases jejejeje